# Using Power Function in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, math, dataframe

i am new to Python and wanted to create a basic pandas dataframe with an index and a column of integers -3,-2-1,1,2,3. After that I wanted to include additional columns taking these integers to various powers. To tidy I replaced NaN with zeros and rounded to two decimals places. The table seems to populate correctly except for those columns: integer column**(-3) and integer column**(-2) e.g. 3**(-3) = 0.04 but the dataframe shows 0. I would be grateful if someone could let me know where I have gone wrong.

```
import pandas as pd

intlist = []

for i in range(-3,0):
    intlist.append(i)

for i in range(1,4):
    intlist.append(i)

df = pd.DataFrame(intlist)

explist = [2/3,-3,-1/4,1/4,3/2,1/3,-2,-1/3]

for j in explist:
    df[str(j)]=df[0]**j

df = df.fillna(0)
df = df.round(2)

print(df)
```

Comment: What python and pandas version are you using? Consider converting the column data type to float before raising the power. `df[0].astype(float)**j`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're getting caught in a weird way Pandas handles exponentiation of an integer with a negative integer. While the standard lib will convert arguments to floats if it sees a negative exponent, it looks like Pandas will try to cast everything to an `int` if it's just working with integers.

Converting either your intlist or your explist to floats *should* solve your problem.

Try replacing your `explist` with this:

```
explist = [2/3, -3., -1/4, 1/4,
           3/2, 1/3, -2., -1/3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your for loop as :

```
for j in explist:
       df[str(j)]=np.power(df[0],float(j))
```

Also import numpy as np for this approach

You can also just use this code in the loop :

```
df[str(j)]=df[0]**float(j)
```